# Is the mask of a structured array supposed to be structured itself?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, structured-array

I was looking into [numpy issue 2972](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2972) and several related problems.  It turns out that all those problems are related to the situation where the array itself is structured, but its mask is not:

```
In [38]: R = numpy.zeros(10, dtype=[("A", "<f2"), ("B", "<f4")])

In [39]: Rm = numpy.ma.masked_where(R["A"]<5, R)

In [41]: Rm.dtype
Out[41]: dtype([('A', '<f2'), ('B', '<f4')])

In [42]: Rm.mask.dtype
Out[42]: dtype('bool')

# Now, both `__getitem__` and `__repr__` will result in errors — see issue #2972
```

If I create a masked array differently, the mask dtype is structured like the dtype of the array itself:

```
In [44]: Q.dtype
Out[44]: dtype([('A', '<f4'), ('B', '<f4')])

In [45]: Q.mask.dtype
Out[45]: dtype([('A', '?'), ('B', '?')])
```

The former situation exposes several problems.  For example, `Rm.__repr__()` and `Rm["A"]` both result in `IndexError`, although it was a `ValueError` in the past.

By design, is the pattern supposed to be possible, where `A.dtype` is structured, but `A.mask.dtype` is not structured?

In other words: is the bug in the `__repr__` and `__getitem__` methods in `numpy.ma.core.MaskedArray`, or is the real bug occurring before — by permitting such a masked structured array to exist in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

The errors in your 1st case indicate that the methods expect the mask to have the same number (and names) of fields as the base array

```
__getitem__:  dout._mask = _mask[indx]
_recursive_printoption: (curdata, curmask) = (result[name], mask[name])
```

If the masked array is make with the 'main' constructor, the mask has the same structure

```
Rn = np.ma.masked_array(R, mask=R['A']>5)
Rn.mask.dtype: dtype([('A', '?'), ('B', '?')])
```

In other words, there is a mask value for each field of each element.

The `masked_array` doc evidently intends for 'same shape' to include `dtype` structure.  `Mask: Must be convertible to an array of booleans with the same shape as 'data'.`

If I try to set the mask in the same way that `masked_where` does

```
Rn._mask=R['A']>5
```

I get the same print error.  The structured mask gets overwritten with the new boolean, changing its dtype.  In contrast if I use

```
Rn.mask=R['A']<5
```

`Rn` prints fine. `.mask` is a property, whose `set` method evidently handles the structured mask correctly.

Without digging into the code history (on github) my guess is that `masked_where` is a convenience function that wasn't updated when structure dtypes were added to other parts of the `ma` code.  Compared to `ma.masked_array` it's a simple function that does not look at the dtype at all.  Other convenience functions like `ma.masked_greater` use `masked_where`.  Changing `result._mask = cond` to `result.mask = cond` might be all that is need to correct this issue.

---

How thoroughly have you tested the consequences of an unstructured mask?

```
Rm.flatten()
```

returns an array with a structured mask, even when it started with an unstructured one.  That's because it uses `Rm.__setmask__`, which is sensitive to fields.  And that's the `set` function for the `mask` property.

```
Rm.tolist()  # same error as str()
```

`masked_where` starts with:

```
cond = make_mask(condition)
```

`make_mask` returns the simple 'bool' dtype.  It can also be called with a dtype, producing a structured mask: `np.ma.make_mask(R['A']<5,dtype=R.dtype)`.  But such a structured mask gets flattened when used in `masked_where`.  `masked_where` not only allows a unstructured mask, it forces it to be unstructured.

Your unstructured mask is already partly implemented, the `recordmask` property:

```
recordmask = property(fget=_get_recordmask)
```

I say partly because it has a `get` method, but the `set` method is not yet implemented.  See `def _set_recordmask(self):`

The more I look at this the more I'm convinced that `masked_where` is wrong.  It could be changed to set a structured mask, but then it's not much different from `masked_array`.  It might better if it raises an error when the array is structured (has `dtype.names`).  That way `masked_where` will remain useful for unstructured numeric arrays, while preventing misapplication to structured ones.

I should also look at the test code.

Comment: I realise all of that.  The question is: Is the bug in `masked_where` (the mask of the structured array should be structured), or is the bug in the other functions (they should expect the mask of a structured array to be either structured or unstructured)?  Logically, both make sense to me, so there is an argument that both should be permitted.  The mask must have the same shape, of course.  But must its dtype also have the same shape?

Comment: I was trying to make the case that the core `ma` functionality assumes a structured mask, and the fact the `masked_where` allows you to set an unstructured mask is a bug, leftover from pre-structured days.