# Does numpy recfunctions append_fields fail when when array names are unicode?

Tags: python, numpy, unicode

I am trying to append an array to a numpy recarray using the numpy.lib.recfunctions append_fields  function.

I receive a "TypeError: data type not understood" error if the recarray field names are unicode.

Is this behaviour as-designed, and if so, is there a work-around?

Using python 2.7 on a Win32 computer.

The code below demonstrates the problem (forgive the additional date-time manipulations - I wanted to create the problem as closely as possible to my original fault):

```
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import numpy.lib.recfunctions as RF

x1=np.array([1,2,3,4])
x2=np.array(['a','dd','xyz','12'])
x3=np.array([1.1,2,3,4])

# this works
FileData = np.core.records.fromarrays([x1,x2,x3],names=['a','b','c'])
# this doesnt
#FileData = np.core.records.fromarrays([x1,x2,x3],names=[u'a',u'b',u'c'])

sDT = ['1/1/2000 12:00:00','1/1/2000 13:00:00','1/1/2000     14:00:00','1/1/2000 15:00:00']
pDT = [datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S') for x in sDT]

# convert to unix timestamp
DT = [ (np.datetime64(dt) - np.datetime64('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z')) /     np.timedelta64(1, 's')  for dt in pDT]

# add datetime to recaray
print FileData.dtype
FileData = RF.append_fields(FileData,'DateTime', data=DT)  #, dtypes='f8'
print FileData.dtype
```

Comment: Digging further I find that both py2 and py3 expect the field names to be strings (as defined by the version).  It's the `fromarrays()` function that is the anomaly, by allowing unicode names in py2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code, with the `unicode` names runs fine under `Python3`, where unicode is the default string type.

---

Edit: Initially I thought the problem lay with masked arrays.  But with further testing, I've concluded that **the real issue is whether `dtype` can accept unicode (in the py2 case) names or not.** Normally the names must be strings (however the version defines them).  But the dictionary style of defining a dtype allows unicode names.  This is the root of why your `fromarrays` works, but not the `append_fields`.

I'm leaving the masked array discussion in place, since that is what you accepted.

### Is it a problem with masked arrays?

Under the 2.7, the full error stack is:

```
  File "stack28586238.py", line 22, in <module>
    FileData = RF.append_fields(FileData,'DateTime', data=DT)  #, dtypes='f8'
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/recfunctions.py", line 633, in append_fields
    base = merge_arrays(base, usemask=usemask, fill_value=fill_value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/recfunctions.py", line 403, in merge_arrays
    return seqarrays.view(dtype=seqdtype, type=seqtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/records.py", line 501, in view
    return ndarray.view(self, dtype, type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/ma/core.py", line 2782, in __array_finalize__
    _mask = getattr(obj, '_mask', make_mask_none(obj.shape, odtype))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/ma/core.py", line 1566, in make_mask_none
    result = np.zeros(newshape, dtype=make_mask_descr(dtype))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/ma/core.py", line 1242, in make_mask_descr
    return np.dtype(_recursive_make_descr(ndtype, np.bool))
TypeError: data type not understood
```

The error occurs in a masked array function, a call like:

```
np.ma.make_mask_none((3,),dtype=[(u'value','f4')])
```

I came across a problem with masked arrays in a previous SO question (not too long ago).  I'll have to see if it's related.

---

[Is the mask of a structured array supposed to be structured itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28182408/is-the-mask-of-a-structured-array-supposed-to-be-structured-itself/28199398#28199398)

isn't directly related, but it does point to some faults when mixing masked arrays and structured array.

[Adding datetime field to recarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26739733/adding-datetime-field-to-recarray/26741206#26741206)
is your earlier SO question regarding `add_fields` focusing on the `datetime` type.

### Or a problem with defining a dtype with unicode names?

By adding `usemask=False` I shift the error to another point, where it is trying to construct a `dtype` from the two component dtype lists: `np.dtype(base.dtype.descr + data.dtype.descr)`.

In 2.7, we can construct a `record array` with unicode names:

```
In [11]: np.core.records.fromarrays([[0,1]],names=[u'test'])
Out[11]: 
rec.array([(0,), (1,)], 
      dtype=[(u'test', '<i4')])
```

But I can't construct a `dtype` directly with unicode name:

```
In [12]: np.dtype([(u'test', int)])
...    
TypeError: data type not understood
```

It appears that **normally the dtype names must be strings**.  In `python3`, `np.dtype([(b'test', int)])` produces the same error.

Also in py3

```
np.core.records.fromarrays([[0,1]],names=[b'test'])
```

produces a `ValueError: field names must be strings`.

`np.core.records.fromarrays` allows unicode because it uses `format_parser`:

```
p=np.format_parser(['int'],[u'test'],[])
p.dtype
# dtype([(u'test', '<i4')])
```

This works because **the dictionary style of dtype definition accepts unicode**:

```
np.dtype({'names':[u'test'],'formats':['int']})
```

Here's an example of merging two structured arrays with unicode names (working in py2):

```
In [53]: dt1 = np.dtype({'names':[u'test1'],'formats':['int']})
In [54]: dt2 = np.dtype({'names':[u'test2'],'formats':['float']})
In [55]: dt12 = np.dtype({'names':[u'test1',u'test2'],'formats':['int','float']})

In [56]: arr1 = np.array([(x,) for x in [1,2,3]],dtype=dt1)
In [57]: arr2 = np.array([(x,) for x in [1,2,3]],dtype=dt2)
In [58]: arr12 = np.zeros((3,),dtype=dt12)

In [59]: RF.recursive_fill_fields(arr1,arr12)
...

In [60]: RF.recursive_fill_fields(arr2,arr12)
Out[60]: 
array([(1, 1.0), (2, 2.0), (3, 3.0)], 
      dtype=[(u'test1', '<i4'), (u'test2', '<f8')])
```

`append_fields` does essentially this (with a few added bells and whistles).

---

I've added a comment to https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2407
`dtype field names cannot be unicode (Trac #1814)`